# How to print null in JSON response without quotes using the "json-c" library?

Tags: c, json

I'd like to keep a field as null (without quotes) in a JSON response object that I'm working on.

I'm using [the "json-c" library](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) and am programming in C.

When I define the null object as a string I get "null"; if I define it as an integer I get 0 as the response.

Is there any way to print just something like `"req_id": null` using this library?

This is what I want the JSON object to look like:

```
{
   "status" : "PROCESSING",
   "request_id" : 85521,
   "result" : null,
   "error" : null
}
```

But this is what it looks like now:

```
{
   "status" : "PROCESSING",
   "request_id" : 85521,
   "result" : "null",
   "error" : "null"
}
```

This is part of my code

```
json_data[2] = { 
    {"result", OBJECT, NULL},//add result object to root object
    {"error", STRING, "null"}//add error to root object
}
resp_obj = ipbt_json_wrapper_api_create_obj(json_data, 2);
```

Comment: Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: i'll add more data into this qn,, gimme  a min

Comment: @GovindhB You can use `com.google.gson.JsonNull.INSTANCE` like this
`JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.add("result", JsonNull.INSTANCE);`
But I don't know this library is exist for `C` or not.

Comment: json-c is the library that i'm using now. Is there something like this in json C library?

Comment: Present your [MCVE]. I see from the code that there is a `json_type_null` enumerator...

Comment: @GovindhB See https://linuxprograms.wordpress.com/category/json-c/

Comment: i've added part of my code with the question.